# How to check if it's null?

Tags: sql, vb.net, null, dataset

I retrieve data from database like below. How do I check whether the value retrieved from database is null?

```
Private Function GetBatch() As DataSet
        Dim dataset As New DataSet
        Dim adapter As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionstring())
        GetBatchCommand.Connection = cn
        adapter = New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(GetBatchCommand)
        adapter.Fill(dataset)
        Return dataset
End Function

Dim dataset As New DataSet
            dataset = GetBatch()

With dataset.Tables(0)

Dim PersonID As String = .Rows(int).Item("personId")
```

I'd like to check whether personID is null. How do do that?

Answer (score 6):

Try [DataRow's IsNull method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx) to check null values :

```
Dim isPersonIDNull As Boolean = .Rows(0).IsNull("personId")
```

Or use [IsDBNull method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(VS.80).aspx) :

```
Dim isPersonIDNull As Boolean = IsDBNull(.Rows(int).Item("personId"))
```

Or manually Check if the value equals DBNull :

```
Dim isPersonIDNull As Boolean = .Rows(int).Item("personId").Equals(DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
If DBNull.Value.Equal(.Rows(int).Item("personId")) Then
...
```

[DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.dbnull.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Convert.DbNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.dbnull.aspx) constant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the value is null before you assign it to PersonID

like:

```
if .Rows(int).Item("personId") = DBNull.Value Then
  ' Assign some Dummy Value
  PersonID = ""
else
  PersonID = .Rows(int).Item("personId") 
end if
```

I would recommend to extract that piece of code into a helper method which gets either the value or a default for a given column.

Answer (score 0):

This situation can occur if table with no rows, that time ds.Table(0).Rows(int).Item("personId") will return null reference exception

so you have to use two conditions

```
Dim PersonID As String =""
if(ds.tables.count>0) Then
 if(ds.tables(0).Rows.Count>0) Then
   if(NOT DBNull.Value.Equal((ds.tables(0).Rows(int).Item("PersonID"))) Then
              PersonID = ds.tables(0).Rows(int).Item("PersonID")
```

I think It will solve your issue..just minor syntax variation may be present